# How do I add a line to the shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am new to Linux OS. I was trying to add custom colors to my terminal using [LS_Colors](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS) Project on Github

I installed the package using `sh install.sh` from the repo.

And it says, To enable the colors, add the following line to your shell's start-up script:

For Bourne shell (e.g. ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc):

```
  . "/home/username/.local/share/lscolors.sh"
```

How and where do I edit that script?

This is my bashrc file

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/home/username/anaconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/home/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/home/username/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ~ is a shorthand for $HOME (or /home/$USER/ or your user directory).  Enter `echo $HOME` to view the contents), so it's suggested `~/.bashrc` already .. which exists on my system as `/home/guiverc/.bashrc` - doesn't your system have it?  (*the alternative is in case you've changed the default BASH to Z Shell*)

Comment: It does, but I am afraid that it doesn't contain any bash setups except for my Conda setup. So that has me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From terminal run:

```
echo '. "/home/abi/.local/share/lscolors.sh"' >> ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

This assumes that your user uses default shell on Ubuntu which is `bash`.

For other shells you need to find out proper initialization file location.

```
man {shell name}
```

e.g.:

```
man zsh
```

After you add this line to your shell initialization script make sure you re-read this file, in case of `bash` invoke:

```
. ${HOME}/.bashrc
```

This solution can be improved still, i.e. you should check if lscolors initialization file exist before you source it in your shell's initialization file, to do that you should open your shell's initialization file in your favorite text editor (geany/gedit/nano/vim/emacs) and add following lines:

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.local/share/lscolors.sh" ] ; then
  . "${HOME}/.local/share/lscolors.sh"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

do as the instructions say,

You can use nano to add that lines to your .bashrc file.
I recommend putting it in the last line, so you can easily find it in the future

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly see which shell you are using:

```
ps -p $$ | grep usr.* --color
```

Then open rc file: .<your shell>rc. For bash it will be .bashrc, for tcsh - .tcshrc. Add "~/" at the beginning of .bashrc as a shortcut to your home directory.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

You will be able to edit it in "gedit" text editor.
Then save and close the gedit window and run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```